# Grunt serve working fine, but have issue with instantiate module after grunt build

Tags: angularjs, npm, gruntjs, bower, yeoman

Facing an issue with grunt build.
Tried everything and also removed all exception getting modules one by one and checked but didn't get any result, and these are the modules currently I am using.

Deployed dist folder in tomcat server.

#### app.js

```
angular
    .module(
            'vendwiseApp',
            [ 'ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch',
                    'ngSanitize', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngMessages',
                    'picardy.fontawesome', 'angular-momentjs', 'FBAngular',
                    'lazyModel', 'toastr', 'angularBootstrapNavTree',
                    'oc.lazyLoad', 'ui.select', 'ui.tree', 'textAngular',
                    'colorpicker.module', 'angularFileUpload', 'ngImgCrop',
                    'datatables', 'datatables.bootstrap',
                    'datatables.colreorder', 'datatables.colvis',
                    'datatables.tabletools', 'datatables.scroller',
                    'datatables.columnfilter', 'ui.grid',
                    'ui.grid.resizeColumns', 'ui.grid.edit',
                    'ui.grid.moveColumns', 'ngTable', 'angular-flot',
                    'easypiechart', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'ui.calendar',
                    'ngTagsInput', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngMaterial',
                    'localytics.directives', 'wu.masonry', 'ipsum',
                    'angular-intro', 'dragularModule', 'base64',
                    'ngIntlTelInput', 'googlechart', 'rt.asyncseries' ])
```

#### console error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngResource due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngResource' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: the error tells you that ngResource can't be found. Make sure that angular-resource.js is served with your application.

Comment: Not only ngResource, if I remove this once it shows other module. Same app working fine with grunt serve.

Comment: you will need to include more information then for others to help. what's the difference between your 'grunt build' and 'grunt serve?' It sounds like grunt build would only build the project and not actually start your server

Comment: Thank you @Ero , there is dependencies issues. Updated angular from 1.5.0 to 1.6.5 everything resolved